# Responsive design for mobile

Tags: html, image, mobile

Im currently buding a responsive mobile site, but im struggling with the final part, where I want the images to be in 2 or 3 columns. The -webkit-column-count float left didnt work.

Below is the html code:

```
<div id="photos"> 
    <span>Some copy should <br> go here</span>
    <a href="#"> 
        <img class="hexagon-link-one" src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="photos">    
    <span class="typetwo">Some copy should <br> go here</span>
    <a href="#"> 
       <img class="hexagon-link-two" src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">                 
    </a>    
</div>  

<div id="photos">        
    <span>Some copy should <br> go here</span>
    <a href="#"> 
       <img class="hexagon-link-one" src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">                 
    </a>    
</div>  

<div id="photos">       
    <span>Some copy should <br> go here</span>
    <a href="#"> 
        <img class="hexagon-link-one" src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">                   
    </a>    
</div>
```

The rest is in the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/4QXkk/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Dom

Comment: you could as well try `width:50%; display: inline-block; box-sizing: border-box; float; left;` on div instead of css3 column-count to show 2 divs per row.

Comment: Thanks Raibaz, that has solved the problem. Dom